# returning amount of times an element appears in list with for loop. python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
DNA = [a,t,g,c] 



 lis = []

    for a in DNA:
        for t in DNA:
            for g in DNA:
                for c in DNA:  
                   lis.append([a,t,g,c])
```

So I created this for loop with all possible combos of strings 'a','t','g','c'  , which returns all 256 combos.

I than created another for loop below, which is supposed to count all of the 'g' strings, which should return a quarter of 256, but it does not do this. It instead returns 256 again, which is the total amount of 'a','t','g','c' strings combined. When I run the below code into a list I
created such as

```
created_DNA_to_check_code = ['a','g','t','a','g','g']
```

it returns the proper amount of 'g' strings, which is 3, so I have no idea why it doesn't work right when ran with the above for loop. Any help would be appreciated

```
def G():
    total = 0
    for g in lis:
        for itr in g: 
            if itr == 'g':

                total += 1
    return total
print(G())
```

Comment: `itertools.product()` would make your code much simpler: `lis = list(itertools.product(DNA, repeat=4))`. Assuming `DNA = ['a', 't', 'g', 'c']` then you get 256 combinations but you get 175 with `g` in it.

Comment: what is `listt`? Your list is called `lst` and you really should pass it in as an argument. And you are not counting the number of items with `g` in it. You are counting the number of `g`s (e.g. `[a, g, g, t]` counts as 2. So you will get 256.

Comment: ```...should return a quarter of 256...``` why do you believe that?

Comment: I actually used that, and it does make it easier. I was really just interested to know why this is happening. The first for loop is creating the same list(from a syntax standpoint) as the       created_DNA_to_check_code = ['a','g','t','a','g','g']      so why is this not working correctly?

Comment: because the 'g' string is one string out of 4 elements

Comment: There are 256 combos , each with 4 characters, so there are ```256 * 4``` characters. 256 of the characters are ```g```'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the number of `g`s, across all the strings so `['g','g','g','g']` would add `4` to your total, which not surprisingly totals `256`.

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> DNA = ['a','g','t','c']
>>> dna = list(it.product(DNA, repeat=4))
>>> len(dna)
256
>>> sum(len(d) for d in dna)
1024
>>> sum(g.count('g') for g in dna)
256
>>> sum(1 for g in dna if 'g' in g)
175
```

`256` is a quarter of `1024` the total number of strings.